# Puppet to chef converter

Tags: converters, chef-infra, puppet

Is there any convertor which converts Puppet scripts to Chef?

I found ruby script which converts Chef scripts to Puppet https://github.com/relistan/chef2puppet but I need puppet2chef.

Comment: This question belongs on http://superuser.com because the technologies you ask about and the conversion between them is a user level configuration problem.  No code involved.

Comment: It's definitely not a superuser.com question. It involves integration of 2 programmers'/sysadmins' tools.

Comment: @EricLeschinski Agreed I'm a chef user and would be interested in tooling in this area

Comment: chef2puppet looks quite outdated to me. And does not work out of the box. Is there any interest in bringing it up to speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE: So, Blueprint is abandonware (last update in 2013). I think the answer to this question is, sadly, now: No.

So, I do not believe there is a 'simple script' way available yet to do this conversion. What I've done in testing is to use [Blueprint](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint) to do the following:

- Install a fresh node with Puppet for the node type you wish to "convert".
- Allow Blueprint to scan the resulting server.
- Use Blueprint to export either Chef or Puppet code.
- Repeat for each node type you have defined in Puppet (or Chef, if you go the other direction).

From the Blueprint README.md:

```
Blueprint reverse-engineers servers.

Easy configuration management.
Detect relevant packages, files, and source installs.
Generate reusable server configs.
Convert blueprints to Puppet or Chef or CFEngine 3.
No DSLs, no extra servers, no workflow changes.
```

I hope I'm proven wrong, and there is a soup-to-nuts script to just "convert" from Puppet to Chef. I'd use it in a heartbeat! :) This method will at least get you started.

Comment: Ah, heh, did it work? If so, please mark my answer. :D

Comment: Kinda sad that Blueprint is now abandonware. It was a neat idea, but a tough problem-space.